# Connect to windows live messenger xmpp with php

Tags: xmpp, windows-live-messenger, xmpphp

How can i connect xmpp windows live messenger with php? I am using xmpphp and jaxl library and I connected with google talk sucsessfully.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaxl library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/) comes with inbuilt support for `PLAIN`, google talk `X-OAUTH2`, `DIGEST-MD5`, `CRAM-MD5`, `SCRAM-SHA-1`, `EXTERNAL` and facebook `X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM` authentication mechanisms.

It does also provide ability to implement any custom authentication mechanism that you might need inside your application. Implementing `X-MESSENGER-OAUTH2` authentication should be easy as described below:

Checkout latest version of [JAXL library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/) and initialize your JAXL client object as follows:

```
require_once 'jaxl.php';
$client = new JAXL(array(
    'jid' => 'messenger.live.com', // <-- dummy jid required for DNS SRV lookup
    'pass' => '',
    'log_level' => JAXL_DEBUG
));
```

Register callback for `on_stream_features` event as shown below and send auth packet as described in [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826554.aspx):

```
$client->add_cb('on_stream_features', function($stanza) {
    global $client, $access_token;
    $auth = new JAXLXml('auth', NS_SASL, array('mechanism'=>'X-MESSENGER-OAUTH2'));
    $auth->t($access_token);
    $client->send($auth);
    return 'wait_for_sasl_response';
});
```

This should get you going.

**Note:** Currently version of Jaxl library rely on input jabber id for DNS SRV lookup, from where it extracts target host:port for establishing socket connection. Hence you will have to pass dummy values for `jid` and `pass` as shown above (until this gets fixed in future versions).

I have written above steps without any testing, but it should work fine. More details on how to work with [JAXLXml](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/tree/v3.x/core/jaxl_xml.php) style of XML creation can be found [here](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2012/09/jaxlxml-strophe-style-xml-builder-working-with-jaxl-a-networking-library-in-php-part-2/).

Comment: Thank for reply. I follow your way but it doesn't work. It got "invalid return value from state handler _waiting for stream feature_